# Script for creating folders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The script below creates folders and subfolders in the Shared Drives. It takes data from Google Sheets where the folder name is in column A. Column C contains the email address of the user who is supposed to be an editor of the created folder.

How to alter the script to add a variable "Email" which can be used to set up the user as the Editor of the created folder.

```js
function createFolder() {
    const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxFolderIDxxxxxxxxxx");
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('1C');
    const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  
    range.getValues().forEach(function (row, index) {
       
        // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
        if(row[0]) {
        var newLink = getLinkForFolderName_(parent, row[0]);
        // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
        range.offset(index, 0, 1).setFormula(
            "HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + row[0] + "\")"
        );
      }
    });
  }

function getLinkForFolderName_(root, name) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }
  else {
  folder = root.createFolder(name);

 
 folder.addEditor('editor@domain.com');
// folder.addEditor(email);


  ["English", "Maths", "Science", "RE", "Humanites", "Music", "Drama", "PE", "MFL", "Computing", "PSHE", "Art/DT", "Enrichment"].forEach(function(e) {
    folder.createFolder(e);
  });
}
}
```

I am new to the Google Apps scripts, when I tried to create the variable I always get the error "var Email is not defined"

Thank you very much.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reccomendation

You would have to expand your range to include the email addresses as well. Currently, the range defined will only capture the folder name that's in column `A`. You can then add another parameter for the email in the function `getLinkForFolderName_`. Also, the `range.offset()` defined in the script will override all entries in column `C` on top of adding the hyperlinked folder name in column`B`. I assume that you would like to only add the hyperlinked folders in column `B` though please let us know and update the question if that is not the case.

Try this code:

```
function createFolder() {
  const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById('0ByUumuULnWJQVVh3SHlkcVpFa3c');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data');
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());

  range.getValues().forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (row[0]) {
      var newLink = getLinkForFolderName_(parent, row[0], row[2]);
      sheet.getRange(index + 2, 2).setFormula("HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + row[0] + "\")");
    }
  });
}

function getLinkForFolderName_(root, name, email) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }else{
    folder = root.createFolder(name);
    folder.addEditor(email);
    ["English", "Maths", "Science", "RE", "Humanites", "Music", "Drama", "PE", "MFL", "Computing", "PSHE", "Art/DT", "Enrichment"].forEach(function (e) {
      folder.createFolder(e);
    });
  }
  return folder.getUrl();
}
```

### References:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now confused even more. Your code works perfectly for one folder. 
But when I created a new sheet, copy and paste the code, changed the folder ID and sheet  name , deployed the script and then ran it, I received an error message: 
 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
createFolder @ Code.gs:4

I tried that on 3 different folders - always with the same error.
Why it is working for one folder but not for another?

M.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The error ` TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange') createFolder` normally means that the script cannot find the specified range. The most common cause is that the sheet with the specified name does not exist. Please note that Apps Script is case sensitive and that spaces between characters or words are counted. To confirm, are you trying it on a completely separate Google Sheets file or on another sheet within the same file?

Comment: My error - I named the file (the left top corner, above the File menu), but not the sheet (the tab on the bottom row). Now everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why the last line of sheets is not processed? Again apart from the first folder all I created later have missing last subfolder (where the name of subfolder is kept in column A.

Thank you very much.

M.

Comment: The range specified in your original script captures the list of folders from A2 to the second to the last row. I suggest changing the range to `const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());`. I've updated the answer as well to reflect it.

Comment: Thank you! That sorted out my problem.

M.